# Recursively comparing elements within a list in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I'm tasked with creating a list of m word portmanteaus with n letter overlap from a given list of words.

For example, a 2 word 2 letter overlap portmanteau would be: "collegenetics" made from "college" and "genetics". A 3 word 2 letter overlap could be "firegaluminum" made of "fire", "regal" and "aluminum".

I have written a function singleport with this syntax:

```
let singleport word1 word2 n = 
match suffix word1 n = prefix word2 n with
| false -> "No Port" 
| true -> word1 ^ (prefixless word2 n)
```

which identifies whether or not two words could be portmanteaus. However, I'm struggling to identify a way to run this recursively in order to compare two elements of a list, all while constructing a new list that records all the possible portmantaus.

I figured List.fold_left could be used because of the use of the accumulator, but I don't know how to implement it and I would greatly appreciate any advice. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches to attack this task is to split it into small understandable subtasks, and then try to merge them. This is the deductive approach.

### Deductively

Applying the deductive method to your task, we can split it in the following way:

1. create a list of consecutive pairs
2. map the list for portmanteaus
3. join the result

To create a list of pairs, you need to write the following function:

```
(** [pair_list xs] given the list [xs], produces a list of consecutive pairs. 
    Fails with an invalid argument, if the list has odd length. *)
val pair_list : 'a list -> ('a * 'a) list
```

With such a function, you can use `map` to transform each pair to a list of portmanteau, mapping a pair to an empty list, if it is impossible. E.g., given this function:

```
val portmanteau : (string * string) -> string list
```

And now we can join everything with `List.concat`:

```
let portmanteau_of_list xs = 
  List.map portmanteau (pair_list xs) |> List.concat
```

### Inductively

Another approach is to move from the opposite direction, i.e., not from top to down, but from the bottom. So inductive reasoning about this task would be the following:

1. portmanteaus of an empty list is an empty list,
2. portmanteaus of the list of one element is an error
3. portmanteaus of a list that is greater than two when the first two elements don't form a portmanteau is the portmanteaus of the rest elements of the list
4. portmanteaus of a list greater than two when the first two elements form a portmanteau is the portmanteaus of these two elements plus portmanteaus of the rest elements of the list.

The same in OCaml (untested):

```
 let rec portmanteau_of_list = function
 | [] -> []
 | [_] -> failwith "odd list"
 | x :: y :: xs -> match portmanteau x y with
   | None -> portmanteau_of_list xs
   | Some p -> p :: portmanteau_of_list xs
```